# Haystack elasticsearch is case-sensitive

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

How to configure haystack elasticsearch for case-insensitive queries?

this is the field in django of my model:

```
text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

isn't it because of the `EdgeNgramField`? should it be just `CharField`? I didn't found any information in the docs about this? or should I set a custom analyzer for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Haystack already works on insensitive queries, we use EdgeNgramField for autocomplete fields,  to perform an autocomplete search. Must be run against fields that are either NgramField or EdgeNgram be https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/autocomplete.html?highlight=EdgeNgramField